# iOS, keyboard goes automatically UP, when touching textarea

Tags: ios, ios6, uikeyboard

As you can see in this [image], the keyboard is going up too high when I touch the textarea. Any idea on what's causing this particular problem. How can I make the keyboard stick to the bottom of screen ?

[UPDATE] (code):

> ```
>   #import "ViewController.h"
>     #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
>     @interface SettingsViewController () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
>     @end
>     @implementation ViewController
>     - (IBAction)feedBack:(id)sender {
>     NSString *iOSVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
>     NSString *model = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
>     NSString *version = @"1.0";
>     MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
>     mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
>    [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"feedback@example.com",nil]];
>    [mailComposer setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Feedback about App V%@",version]];
>    NSString *supportText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device: %@\niOS Version:%@\n\n",model,iOSVersion];
>    supportText = [supportText stringByAppendingString: @"Please write your feedback or suggestions"];
>    [mailComposer setMessageBody:supportText isHTML:NO];
>    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
>    }
>     - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:    (MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
>    {
>    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
>    }
> ```

Comment: That's not default behavior, so unless you show some code it will be difficult to determine what causes that.

Comment: How are you presenting the view controller?

Comment: heh that's ultra-weird.  wild guess, are you using inputAccessoryView anywhere?

Comment: @Vrasidas, I've updated my post, that is all the code.

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm not using inputAccessoryView.

Comment: Nothing in the code suggests a problem, maybe it's something in your xib file?

Comment: I've looked into the xib file, but nothing there, a simple tableview is there, that's it

Comment: It looks like its sizing the keyboard for a 3.5 inch screen, is the rest of the view (before the keyboard shows) being cut off as well?

Comment: Does this same thing happen on a 3.5 inch screen?

Comment: What are the bounds of your app window ? Try logging the `self.view.window.bounds`. That might point you to your problem.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer, I have done this : `NSLog(@"frame w:%f h:%f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);NSLog(@"bounds w:%f h:%f", self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);`

Comment: I got this : 
frame w:320.000000 h:455.000000
bounds w:320.000000 h:455.000000

Comment: Do this once : `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.window.bounds))`. From your Log statements, I can see that the view frame is actually smaller than the iPhone screens (both 5 and 4). If your window size is not equal to the screen size, that is where your problem lies.
PS. Try changing the default-image (splash screen) of your app. In many cases, it has been known to screw with the window size of your app.

Comment: Here is it : `{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}`

Comment: By the way, this problem is showing only in iOS6, iOS7 no problem !

Answer (score -2):

That has nothing to do with your code. The *user* can move the keyboard from the bottom of the screen or split it. *You* have done exactly that as the user. You, as the user, need to drag the keyboard down again if that's what you want.

And you don't do anything about it, because it is behaviour that the user *intentionally* chose. For people who write code that keeps track of the keyboard appearing / disappearing and moving items out of the area covered by the keyboard: If the keyboard is undocked or split, or if the user uses a hardware keyboard, you will get no notifications about the area covered by the keyboard.

Comment: User can't slide keyboard down, you still get notifications with a hardware keyboard, and an ios keyboard not locking to the bottom of the screen is anything but default behavior.

Comment: Have you tried it? Splitting keyboard in two -> no notifications. Undocking keyboard -> no notifications.

Comment: I didn't say that splitting / undocking would give you notifications.  I said, hardware keyboard would still give notifications, and on an iPhone(the device in question), you can't undock/slide the keyboard.